# firebase $add() .push() .set()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am using firebase, and angularfire.
there are so many ways to do CRUD with the Firebase Api
actually, I still don't get what is specific difference for using

- $add with $firebaseArray
- .push() method
- .set() method

I think they are technically same, I prefer to use .set method() without knowing the exact reason, why I'd using that. is there any specific reason to not use it? what is exactly $firebaseArray did? if we could just declare basic reference variable.

in this case:

```
var usersRef = Ref.child('users');

  $scope.createUser = function() {
    $scope.userRef.child($id).set({
       name: name
           });
      };
```

or

```
$scope.data = $firebaseArray(Ref.child('users'));

$scope.createUser = function() {
  $scope.data.child($id).$add({
    name: name
  });
 };
```

thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I have the following data tree in Firebase:

```
{
  users:
   {
      key: { name:"bob" }
   }
}
```

When I do an $add, I will create a new item in the tree

```
$scope.data.child('users').$add({
    name: name
  });
```

Since $add uses the Push method in Firebase, new random Key will be used when pushing data to the child.

```
{
  users:
   {[
      key: { name:"bob" },
      key2: { name:"name" }
   ]}
}
```

If I do a set on the same Users object, I will overwrite the data that is already there. So, in your example, without specifying a key, you will overwrite the entire user object.

```
$scope.userRef.child('users').set({
       name: name
           });
      };
```

This will result with this data

```
{
  users:
   {
      name: "name"
   }
}
```

This happens because any null values you pass to the Set method will delete any data that was originally there.

> Passing null to set() will remove the data at the specified location.
>   https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html