# Improved way to rollback a list of 'push' into firebase

Tags: javascript, loops, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of multiples earthquakes registries (*around 200, just put 2 for the sake of the example*):

```
{
  "EVENTS" : {
    "-Yn6oKFQdn5s24R" : {
      "event" : {
        "date" : "22/04/18",
        "time" : "10:01:45",
        "place" : "Some place"
      },
      "timestamp" : "Mon Apr 23 2018 12:05:00 GMT-0600"
    },
    "-R96Yn6oKFQdn5s" : {
      "event" : {
        "date" : "23/04/18",
        "time" : "11:02:45",
        "place" : "Some place"
      },
      "timestamp" : "Mon Apr 23 2018 12:05:00 GMT-0600"
    }
  }
}
```

> How this list works? (on my server)

- Every time a new event is detected, is added to the list.
- Sometimes, the event may has not been detected.
  correctly and needs an update, or it needs to be deleted for some other
  reason.
- The list has a limit, and when new events are added, some other
  events are deleted from the list

So, when I'm going to `push` the list on `firebase` for any reason the list on the server has changed, I don't want to look which registries has changed, or updated, instead I prefer to delete the complete list and populate it again.

> The problem I'm thinking

What if after I delete the list on `firebase`, and when I'm pushing, some request fails? If this happen, my list on `firebase` would be empty.

> What I have

I have made a code that first, save the existing keys, make the push. If some registry fails, delete the new keys added, and if not, delete the saved keys on the first step and keeps the new added.

> So, my question

Is there some improved way in `Firebase Real Time Database`, in which I can deal with this situation? I have read about `transactions`, but I don't know if this can help.

Comment: As always, my questions about `firebase` are neither answered or commented by anyone :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, based on my specific case, I found that is more usefull to accomplish exaclty what I need, with `.set()` instead of `.push()`.

**Why?**

- If I do a `.set()` on the list, it'l overwrite the data that is already
  there; it doesn't matter which registry has been changed, or if it's has been removed previously in my server for any reason, `.set()` keeps the order for me.
- I don't have to make a `.remove()` of all the data in the list when I want to update it, because *-as I said before-* this method keeps the order in an awesome way.

**Example of what I said:**

- [firebase $add() .push() .set()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36572516)

---

**Bonus 1:**

As a comment, I want to prevent to do not confuse `.push().set()` with `.set()`. Why? Because the former *-in the Firebase JavaScript SDK-* do the same than `.push()`. [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47125842)

**Bonus 2:**

If you want to empty the list with `.set()`, you only need to pass a `null` for the new value, because doing that, is equivalent to calling `.remove()`. Awesome !

See more of all of this on the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write), and [firebase.database.Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) for all the detailed methods.